# How to speed up a function in GPU for model training using Keras

Tags: python, keras, gpu, conv-neural-network

I am applying a preprocessing function on each image before training the model using Keras, the problem is that this complex function is taking time, even on Google Colab Pro (based on GPU), when I don't use this function the training go fast, so now, I need a way that help me to use this function without altering the speed of the training, I tried Numba library but it doesn't work for me since my function calling many other libraries.

```
#@cuda.jit
def my_func(image):
  image = image.astype('uint8')
  image = n.transform(image)
  return image.astype('float64') 

  data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255.0,vertical_flip=True, 
                                   horizontal_flip=True,
                                    preprocessing_function=my_func)
```

Comment: IT is not possible to run code like that on your GPU using Numba.

Comment: so, how can i do that ?

Comment: Do what? I have already explained that you cannot run arbitrary python code (especially code that uses compiled libraries like keras) on your GPU. There is no such thing as a free lunch, as they say.

Answer (score 0):

try creating a layer that handles your input data inside the network.

```
class customFn(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(customFn, self).__init__()

    def call(self, inputs):
        result=tf.math.divide(tf.math.divide(tf.math.square(tf.multiply(inputs,255)),255),255)
        #you should rewrite your original function based on tensorflow functions
        #like tf.math.divide
        return result

def giveModel():
    with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
        inputs=layers.Input(shape=inputShape)
        x=customFn()(inputs) #use it as usual
        x=layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),(1,1),activation='relu')(x)
        #and story goes on ...
```